# Posted solution to problem seems to contain unnecessary code

Tags: javascript

The attached snippet is a posted solution to a homework problem for CS50 mobile app dev.  I'm confused about one function.

```
Todo.prototype.toggleCheck = function() {
  this.checked = !this.checked
  if (this.element && this.checkbox) {
    this.checkbox.checked = this.checked
  } else {
    this.element = renderTodo(this)
  }
}
```

It seems that the if else statement is not needed. NOTE: in the renderTodo function checkbox.checked = todo.checked

The program seems to work fine if we delete the conditional.  Am I missing something?

```js
const classNames = {
  DELETE_BUTTON: 'delete-button',
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountDiv = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountDiv = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

let todos = []

function count(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, next) => fn(next) ? acc + 1 : acc, 0)
}

function Todo(name) {
  this.name = name || 'New TODO'
  this.checked = false
  this.element = null
  this.checkbox = null
}

Todo.prototype.toggleCheck = function() {
  this.checked = !this.checked
  if (this.element && this.checkbox) {
    this.checkbox.checked = this.checked
  } else {
    this.element = renderTodo(this)
  }
}

function renderTodo(todo) {
  if (todo.element) return todo.element

  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
  deleteButton.innerHTML = '&times'
  deleteButton.className = classNames.DELETE_BUTTON
  // keep reference of todo on button so that it can be dereferenced in the callback
  deleteButton.onclick = removeTodo
  deleteButton.todoRef = todo

  const checkbox = document.createElement('input')
  checkbox.className = classNames.TODO_CHECKBOX
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox'
  checkbox.checked = todo.checked
  checkbox.todoRef = todo
  checkbox.onchange = toggleChecked
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.className = classNames.TODO_TEXT
  span.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')
  span.innerHTML = todo.name

  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.className = classNames.TODO_ITEM
  li.appendChild(deleteButton)
  li.appendChild(checkbox)
  li.appendChild(span)


  // keep reference of element on todo for performance
  todo.element = li
  todo.checkbox = checkbox

  return li
}

function render() {
  list.innerHTML = ''
  todos.map(renderTodo).forEach(todo => list.appendChild(todo))
  uncheckedCountDiv.innerHTML = count(todos, todo => !todo.checked)
  itemCountDiv.innerHTML = todos.length
  return false
}

function addTodo(name) {
  const todo = new Todo(name)
  todos.push(todo)
  return render()
}

function toggleChecked() {
  this.todoRef.toggleCheck()
  return render()
}

function removeTodo() {
  const todo = this.todoRef
  todos = todos.filter(t => t !== todo)
  return render()
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flow-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title, .controls, .button {
  flex: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.delete-button {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.todo-container:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="addTodo()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems like the conditional allows the `toggleCheck` method to be called on instances that have not yet been rendered. That might not occur in the example use case, but maybe the code is used elsewhere as well.

Comment: seems kind of wacky to toggle something you can't see.  Thanks for the feedback